# Working Python script throw out error when PHP calls it with exec

Tags: php, python, anaconda, theano

I have a simple php code:

```
<?php echo exec('/opt/anaconda2/bin/python test2.py 2>&1'); ?><br>
```

And `test2.py` simply import a library called `theano`

```
import theano
```

It works under ssh but throw out:

```
KeyError: 'PATH'
```

when looking at the php in browser.

What's happeneing here? Is there any way that I can see full trace of error msg?

Comment: I'm not sure what a KeyError is from your python script, but I suspect that the environment and working directory that are in effect when you execute it via ssh is not the same as when you executive via apache. The user is probably different (www-data or apache or httpd instead of your ssh user) and the working directory might also be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for the PHP side of things, but I think KeyError is a Python thing:

```
<?php 

$output = array();

exec('/opt/anaconda2/bin/python test2.py 2>&1', $output, $returnCode); 

echo 'Output is: ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($output);
echo 'Return code is: ' . PHP_EOL;
var_dump($returnCode);

?>
```